# Why does Italian word sì lose the ì in TextView?

Tags: android, utf-8, internationalization, textview

In the textview, all I see is "s"  when I should have "sì"

My values-it/strings.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <string name="msg_yes">sì</string>
```

And my code:

```
    txtMsg.setText(R.string.msg_yes);
```

Comment: Are you using the system default font? Are you sure this font contains the accented character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested on my Samsung Nexus S running Jellybean by copying/pasting and I found that both in the preview pane and on my device the character was displayed correctly. This may have to do with OS version, phone, font, theme, or some other factor...

Comment: It was the font. I was using a custom font.

Comment: I'm glad you found a resolution.